# Resize page number field in ext.pagingtoolbar

Tags: javascript, extjs, pagination

By default the page number field in `Ext.PagingToolbar` takes only 2 digits. How to increase this?

http://jsfiddle.net/bNTsd/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set it via:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging-cfg-inputItemWidth

"The width in pixels of the input field used to display and change the current page number."